# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I know it has been asked too many times here but I can't still resolve the issue. I have tried solutions provided in previous questions but they are not working somehow.

Here's my gradle dependency -

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0'
compile project(':IndicatorLib')
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.0'
// GMS in the library was causing merging error, we need to exclude the duplicate dependencies
compile ('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.0') { exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'}
```

Here's my gradle dependencies output -

```
_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.1.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22) -> 23.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4
+--- project :IndicatorLib
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.1.0 (*)
+--- com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0
+--- com.github.clans:fab:1.5.0
\--- io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.0
     \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1 -> 23.1.0

_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.1.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22) -> 23.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4
+--- project :IndicatorLib
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.1.0 (*)
+--- com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0
+--- com.github.clans:fab:1.5.0
\--- io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.0
     \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1 -> 23.1.0
```

From what I think, `smartlocation` library is the main culprit which is causing the issue since if I remove this library, the app is building correctly. According to the [build.gradle](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib/blob/master/library/build.gradle) of the library, the only thing I think which can conflict is `GMS` library, for which I have added exclude but this is also giving the same error. What else can I do to resolve the problem?

**Update :-**

Here's the error log -

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    F:\Android SDK\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output F:\Android Projects\Office Projects\Git Synced\new\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=F:\Android Projects\Office Projects\Git Synced\new\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java
```

:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Comment: What is the full error that you are seeing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error means your application and the libraries it references reach a certain size, you encounter build errors that indicate your app has reached a limit of the Android app build architecture.

So you have to make it [`MultiDexApplication`](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Part of gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Create a class that extends `MultiDexApplication` and define that class in manifest

class

```
public class CustomMultiDexApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

     @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        android:name="your.package.name.CustomMultiDexApplication">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

One tip as `support v7` includes `support v4` so don't need to add dependency of `v4` library.

Comment: I'll try it, so it means that I might have used too many libraries and the Dex overflow has occurred?

Comment: yes @RohanKandwal and minimum sdk version should be `14`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, while I try your solution, I have another question. Does multidexing an app makes it heavy? I mean will the app's performance be affected anyhow?

Comment: Frankly I don't have much knowledge I faced this issue the day before yesterday and I solved it using this I noticed one thing it is taking time when I make a build(which is mentioned in developer site's too) but no performance issue still now

Comment: Thanks man, it's working now. I wasted an entire day thinking that the problem is due to duplicate library issue. Will mark your answer by evening might get some other good advises.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93850/discussion-between-kaushik-and-rohan-kandwal).